# Rewrite $[p_1(x)\geq 0 \text{ and } p_2(x)\geq 0] \Rightarrow q(x)\geq 0$, $[-p_1(x)\geq 0 \text{ and } -p_2(x)\geq 0] \Rightarrow q(x)\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to reformulate an optimisation problem with unknown $x$ into a mixed-integer program. In this respect, I would like your help to rewrite the following constraints
$$
\begin{cases}
p_1(x)\geq 0 \text{ and } p_2(x)\geq 0 \Rightarrow q(x)\geq 0\\
-p_1(x)\geq 0 \text{ and } -p_2(x)\geq 0 \Rightarrow q(x)\geq 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $p_1:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $p_2:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $q:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $p_1, p_2, q$ linear in $x$.

using the big-M modelling approach. These questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991472/rewrite-the-constraint-px-0-rightarrow-qx-0-in-an-optimization-problem) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949764/transform-an-optimisation-problem-into-a-linearly-constrained-quadratic-program) are related.

---

If I had only to consider 
$$
\Big[ p_1(x)\geq 0 \text{ and } p_2(x)\geq 0 \Big] \Rightarrow q(x)\geq 0\\
$$
I think the correct procedure would have been to model the following implications with $\delta_1, \Delta_{1,1}, \Delta_{1,2}$ binary
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta_{1,1}=1\\
\Delta_{1,2}=1
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \delta_1=1 \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
p_1(x)\geq 0\\
p_2(x)\geq 0\\
q(x)\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
leading to 
$$
\begin{cases}
p_1(x)+\epsilon\leq M_1*\Delta_{1,1}\\
p_2(x)+\epsilon\leq M_1*\Delta_{2,1}\\
\delta_1\geq 1+\Delta_{1,1}+\Delta_{2,1}-2\\
q(x)\geq -M_1(1-\delta_1)\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $\epsilon$ is added to activate $q(x)\geq -M_1(1-\delta_1)$ also when $p_1(x)=p_2(x)=0$.

I have doubts on what happens when instead we consider

$$
\Big[p_1(x)\geq 0 \text{ and } p_2(x)\geq 0 \Big] \text{ or } \Big[-p_1(x)\geq 0 \text{ and } -p_2(x)\geq 0 \Big]\Rightarrow q(x)\geq 0\\
$$

Specifically, I don't know whether we have to double the number of auxiliary binary variables (option 1 below) or we can keep the same number of auxiliary binary variables (option 2 below).

---

**Option 1**
$$
\begin{cases}
p_1(x)+\epsilon\leq M_1*\Delta_{1,1}\\
p_2(x)+\epsilon\leq M_1*\Delta_{2,1}\\
\delta_1\geq 1+\Delta_{1,1}+\Delta_{2,1}-2\\
q(x)\geq -M_1(1-\delta_1)\\
-------------\\
\color{blue}{-p_1(x)+\epsilon\leq M_2*\Delta_{1,2}}\\
\color{blue}{-p_2(x)+\epsilon\leq M_2*\Delta_{2,2}}\\
\color{blue}{\delta_2\geq 1+\Delta_{1,2}+\Delta_{2,2}-2}\\
\color{blue}{q(x)\geq -M_2(1-\delta_2)}\\
-------------\\
\delta_1\in \{0,1\}\\
\delta_2\in \{0,1\}\\
\Delta_{1,1}\in \{0,1\}\\
\Delta_{2,1}\in \{0,1\}\\
\Delta_{1,2}\in \{0,1\}\\
\Delta_{2,2}\in \{0,1\}\\
\end{cases}
$$

**Option 2**

$$
\begin{cases}
p_1(x)+\epsilon\leq M_1*\Delta_{1,1}\\
p_2(x)+\epsilon\leq M_1*\Delta_{2,1}\\
\delta_1\geq 1+\Delta_{1,1}+\Delta_{2,1}-2\\
q(x)\geq -M_1(1-\delta_1)\\
-------------\\
q(x)\geq -M_1(1-\color{blue}{(1-\delta_1)})\\
-------------\\
\delta_1\in \{0,1\}\\
\Delta_{1,1}\in \{0,1\}\\
\Delta_{2,1}\in \{0,1\}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: could you indicate the implications you have modeled?

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks: I have added some clarifications (I hope in line with your request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With option 2, if $p_i$ is negative, $\Delta_{i,1}$ could be anything. Therefore, you never force $\delta_i$ to take the value 1. Moreover, option 2 has the constraints $q(x) \geq -M_1(1-\delta_1)$ and $q(x) \geq -M_1 \delta_1$, so you always force $q(x) \geq 0$, independent of the value taken by $\delta_1$.

Option 1 is a correct reformulation.